# Python: Elegant way of 3d geometry manilupation

Tags: python

Here is a list of 3d points, how can I set its coordinate value elegantly?

```
rectangle = [(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,0)]
# how rectangle.z = z0 ?
# => rectangle = [(0,0,z0),(0,1,z0),(1,1,z0),(1,0,z0)]
```

Comment: `rectangle = [tuple(list(i[:2]) + [z_value]) for i in rectangle]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[(x, y, z0) for (x, y, _) in rectangle]
```

Comment: After hanging around for a while, I think I should resort to `Numpy`, and that should be the answer.

Comment: for munching numbers, always a good idea ;) It all depends on scope of your program, right?

Comment: @cqcn1991 feel free to add your own answer, if you have found solution better for you. It is perfectly OK here on SO, even encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Slice each tuple in the list and then append the z value to each with a comprehension:

```
rectangle = [i[:2] + (z_value,) for i in rectangle]
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks, forgot that tuples could be concatenated.